# What is the result of $\lim \limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3}{3}(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{3}{x^3}}-1)$?

Tags: limits

I think the result is 0 because the term $\frac{3}{x^3}$ equals to 0 when $x\to\infty$ so $\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{3}{x^3}}=\sqrt[3]{1+0}=1$ then the last state of the limit is $\lim \limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3}{3}(1-1)=0$.

Symbolab can't solve the problem, Wolfram Alpha and Microsoft Mathsolver give $\frac{1}{3}$ result.

How can this limit equal to $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: It's because $x^3$ approaches infinity faster than the terms inside the brackets approach zero.

Comment: You stop the reasoning halfway. The expression tends to... $\infty\cdot0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Use $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab)$$with $$a=\sqrt[3]{1+{3\over x^2}}\\b=1$$

Comment: Wow! This is really cool. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!.

Answer (score 1):

You split the limit in the sequences $a(x) = \frac{x^3}{3}$ and $b(x) = \sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{3}{x^3}} - 1$, and calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty} b(x) = 0$. Then you want to conclude 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} a(x) b(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} a(x) \lim_{x \to \infty} b(x) = 0.
\end{align*}
However, this can only be done if $\lim{x \to \infty} a(x)$ exists and is finite, whereas $\lim_{x\to \infty} a(x) = \infty$.

To calculate $\lim_{x\to \infty} a(x) b(x)$ you can use the Taylor series of $\sqrt[3]{1 + \frac{3}{x^3}} = 1 + \frac{1}{x^3} + O(x^{-6})$ to write $a(x)b(x) = \frac{1}{3} + O(x^{-3})$ and use this to calculate the limit.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac3{x^3}}=1+h$

$\implies h\to0$

The limit becomes $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac h{(1+h)^3-1}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the binomial expansion at order $1$: near $0$,
$$(1+u)^{1/3}=1+\frac13u+o(u).$$
Substituting $u=\frac3{x^3}$, you obtain
$$\sqrt[3]{1+\frac3{x^3}}=1+\frac1{x^3}+o\Bigl(\frac1{x^3}\Bigr),$$
whence
$$\frac{x^3}{3}\biggl(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{3}{x^3}}-1\biggr)=\frac{x^3}3\biggl(\frac{1}{x^3}+o\Bigl(\frac1{x^3}\Bigr)\biggr)=\frac13+o(1).$$